# YouTube Data API not returning scheduled live streams

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm working on a site that lists upcoming live streams from a specific YouTube channel. This has recently stopped working without there being any changes to either the code of the YouTube account for the channel

The below request returns an empty items array even though the channel has upcoming live streams:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=upcoming&type=video&channelId=UCvME6kEF02MqliB5TNHFLZA&maxResults=50&key=`

Below is the URL for the upcoming live streams displayed on the YouTube website:

`https://www.youtube.com/user/ClaytonTelevision/videos?view=2&sort=dd&live_view=502&shelf_id=20`

I have done a few tests with the API by swapping the Channel ID to different channels, but these are working fine